# Set default application for filetype

Tags: finder

I see a file of a particular type and it defaults to opening in the wrong program. I right-clicked the file, held down <kbd>Option</kbd>, and selected `Always open with` and then the correct application. The file opened in the right app, but it did not change the default. How can I set the default for a file's type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the file and go to `Get info` (shortcut: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). There will be an option to set that file's default application. Select it and use `Change All...` to make the default apply to all others of the type.

:::::::::::::::::::::::::[image: Get info, Open with, Change All...]